# Inconsistent results from executed method within application issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, methods

Although the following method-call:

```
GlobalCacheAdaptor.Instance.SendIR("sendir," + activeRoom[3] + ",1,40000,4,1,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,800" + Environment.NewLine);
```

works perfectly when called from one part of my C# application, unfortunately, the same method-call fails and returns an exception claiming that the "socket (_deviceSocket) cannot be null" when called from another part of my application.

```
public void SendIR(string message)
{
  try
        {
            var stream = new NetworkStream(_deviceSocket);
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream) {NewLine = "\r", AutoFlush = true};
            _deviceWriter = writer;
            _detectedRelayModule = -1;
            writer.WriteLine(message);
            var readerThread = new Thread(ReaderThreadProc) {IsBackground = true};
            readerThread.Start(reader);
        }
 catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show( e.GetBaseException().ToString());
        }
 }
```

Would someone kindly steer me in the right direction as to what needs modification so that the method-call works consistently throughout the application?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from your code. Most likely, you have a multithreading issue. Check when `_deviceSocket` is set to `null`. Maybe it will lead you somewhere.

Comment: Daniel - it did turn out to be a threading issue.  After reading more about threading, I learned about Anonymous Methods.  After adding the following code to the class:

public delegate void DelegateClass(string Zone);
public DelegateClass Z630_Power = delegate(string Zone)
{
Instance.SendIR("sendir," + Zone + ",1,40000,4,1,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,181,21,800" + Environment.NewLine);
};

I was able to implement the method with the following call:

GlobalCacheAdaptor.Instance.Z630_Power(activeRoom[3]);  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that `_deviceSocket` is being closed for you by the (presumably) other `NetworkStream`? ([System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx) being an IDisposable class.) However without more code (the initialisation of _deviceSocket and it's other use) I can't be certain.